# Cannot read property `left` of `undefined` in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check `div` come on `viewport` or `not`, but I am getting this error:

> Cannot read property `left` of `undefined`

On `scroll` event, I am checking which div present in the viewport like so:

```
( "#container" ).scroll(function() {
      console.log('scrlling');
      $.each( $('#container>div'), function(i, left) {
           console.log(i);
           var msid= $(left).attr('data-msid');
           console.log($(left).attr('data-msid'));
           console.log($(left['data-msid='+msid]).isOnScreen())

          })
    });
```

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/Du5J120AIkNqnnpR30le?p=preview

Comment: Did you try to use $(this) instead of $(left)?

// Example
var msid= $(this).attr('data-msid');

Comment: Hmmm... Just doesn't seem *right*.

Comment: I want to check which `div` in is viewport ..I want to check with this `attr`  `data-msid'`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this statement:

```
console.log($(left['data-msid='+msid]).isOnScreen())
```

Instead of filtering `$(left)` to make sure it has a `data-msid` of `msid`, you are running a dynamic property access on `left` (due to the square bracket notation). Since `left` is a DOM node, it does not have any property beginning with `data-msid=` and so the property access returns `undefined`. Thus, your code is run as something like this:

```
console.log($(undefined).isOnScreen())
```

I am guessing that `isOnScreen()` checks a `left` property at some point, and since the only thing that was passed to jQuery was `undefined` it is not hard to imagine an error being thrown here eventually.

### The Updated Code:

```js
$("#container").scroll(function() {
  console.log('scrolling');
  $('#container > div').each(function (i, left) {
    console.log(i);
    var msid = $(left).attr('data-msid');
    console.log(msid);
    console.log($(left).isOnScreen());
  })
});
```